# I cannot make echo display the name with an _ symbol

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I am new at this and I'll simplify my problem. I doing the following script:

```
echo "Insert number of elements:" 
read elements

echo "Insert md number:" 
read sim

echo "uni_$elements_md$sim.tpr" >> doc.bash
```

But when I run the doc.bash file it only shows inside:

```
uni_4.tpr
```

Please help me, how must I do my `ech`o so that if I put `elements` as `14` and `sim` as `4` (just to put an example), it displays:

```
uni_14_md4.tpr
```

Thanks.

Comment: `${elements}_md`.

Comment: Because `_` is a valid character in a variable name, so bash thinks you want the `elements_md` variable. Use braces to surround the variable name: `echo "uni_${elements}_md$sim.tpr"`. You don't need braces around `sim` because dot is not a valid varname char, although for symmetry it might be more readable to add braces there too.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick responsa. It worked perfect.